# Converting string to number with in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm consuming an external API where I'm not in control of the data format. The response from that API can contain a field, where the content can be both strings and numbers.

The result of this response is also what I'm going to use as body in another POST request. But for the API I'm submitting this to, it does of course expect the value to be a number instead of a string (unless there is actually text there).

I hope this describes a bit more of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm new to JS, so sorry if the terms are not correct :)

```json
{
    "someField": "someValue",
    "card": {
        "someFields": [
            {
                "key": "merchant",
                "label": "Merchant",
                "value": "Demo" <--- This one can contain both a text value and numbers. 
            },
            {
                "key": "member",
                "label": "member",
                "value": "123123123123" <--- This one can contain both a text value and numbers. 
            }
        ],
        "someOtherFields": [
            {
                "key": "balance",
                "label": "Balance",
                "value": "0" <--- This one can contain both a text value and numbers. 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want it to output something like this:

```json
{
    "someField": "someValue",
    "card": {
        "someFields": [
            {
                "key": "merchant",
                "label": "Merchant",
                "value": "Demo"
            },
            {
                "key": "member",
                "label": "member",
                "value": 123123123123
            }
        ],
        "someOtherFields": [
            {
                "key": "balance",
                "label": "Balance",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried the following, but after passing it to JSON.stringify, the value is still like "0" instead of 0.

```js
const parseData = JSON.parse(data, replaceNum);
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(parseData);

function replaceNum(key, value) {
  if (key == "value") {
    return parseInt(value) ? parseInt(value) : value;
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON fields should contain a number only if you expect to treat it as a number.  It's problematic to mix your metaphors this way.

Comment: That said, the best way to solve this is probably to deserialize it in the usual way and then write code that does a numeric check and a conversion to a numeric field after it is deserialized.

Comment: *"when using JSON.stringify"*: can you provide code where you call `JSON.stringify`? This part confuses me.

Comment: I would say that using something called "stringify" to turn something into a number is probably not the appropriate route. Did you perhaps mean `JSON.parse`? Because [that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) takes a function that would be helpful.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` won't help you create `number` primitives.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parseInt to check if the incoming value is a string.

> "value": parseInt(item.value) ? parseInt(item.value) : item.value

```js
let inputData = [
            {
                "key": "merchant",
                "label": "Merchant",
                "value": "Demo" 
            },
            {
                "key": "member",
                "label": "member",
                "value": "123123123123"
            }
        ]

let outputData = inputData.map(item=>{
  return {
                "key": item.key,
                "label": item.label,
                "value": parseInt(item.value) ? parseInt(item.value) : item.value
            }
});

console.log(outputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a *reviver* function with a check for a finite number.

```js
const
    json = '{"number":"123.45e34","string":"some text"}',
    result = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => typeof v === 'string' && Number.isFinite(v) ? + v : v);

console.log(result);
```